# unable to update the record in triggered table when new record is found in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

unable to write a trigger to insert a row if no imei found in the triggered table if found then it should update the record.

> query error - lost connection to my sql server.

```
  DELIMITER $$
    create TRIGGER update_livedata4
    AFTER INSERT ON `Rawdata`
    FOR EACH ROW
    begin 
     IF Livedata.IMEI <> Rawdata.IMEI THEN
           INSERT INTO Livedata(IMEI,updatedTime,latitude,longitude,speed,ignition,fuel,altitude,battery,runHrs,alert,distance) VALUES (NEW.IMEI,NEW.updatedTime, NEW.latitude,NEW. longitude,NEW.speed,NEW.ignition,NEW.fuel,NEW.altitude,NEW.battery,NEW.runHrs,NEW.alert,NEW.distance);
        END IF;
    UPDATE Livedata SET IMEI = new.IMEI,updatedTime=new.updatedTime,latitude= NEW.latitude,longitude=NEW. longitude,speed=NEW.speed,ignition=NEW.ignition,fuel=NEW.fuel,altitude=NEW.altitude,battery=NEW.battery,runHrs=NEW.runHrs,alert=NEW.alert,distance=NEW.distance;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing where clause in the update that you have written which in turn takes more than your net read timeout....!

Are you willing to update all the records?

If that is the case then increasing the timeout would help...

Comment: im just creating trigger there is 2 or 3 records in the triggered table- livedata. i was trying if imei is found in any row that row should be updated.may be i need to write the where clause but i dont know how to pic the imei of the triggered table. i want to update only 1 record. i have set read time to 1 min also

Comment: you can use old and new keywords to get values from tables...